# setOnItemSelectedListener in the Spinner not calling

Tags: android, button, spinner

I have such a method for items adding:

```
timezoneEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             timezonSpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timezoneSpin);//timezoneCall();  
           final ArrayList <String> timezonelist = new ArrayList<String>();

            timezonelist.add("Gvatemala");
            timezonelist.add("Gonduras");
            timezonelist.add("Batumi");
            timezonelist.add("Boston");
            timezonelist.add("Zhytomir");
            timezonelist.add("Zmerinka");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewOrderActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, timezonelist);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            timezonSpin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);timezonSpin.performClick(); 
            timezonSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {

                    Log.i("sd","Ya tut");
                    Log.i("choosed",timezonelist.get(position).toString());
                    timezoneEdit.setText(timezonelist.get(position));
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                    TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
                    String TimeZoneName = timezone.getDisplayName();
                    int TimeZoneOffset = timezone.getRawOffset()/(60 * 60 * 1000);
                    Log.i("timezone",Integer.toString(TimeZoneOffset));
                    timezoneEdit.setText("UTC"+Integer.toString(TimeZoneOffset), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                }
         });
```

When user clicks on button, spinner is showing and user can choose one of the items. But weird thing is that onItemSelectedListener is not calling. I use such shema for my other regular spinners(without button click using) and everything works fine there...What's the missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
timezoneEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             Spinner timezonSpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timezoneSpin);//timezoneCall();  
           final ArrayList <String> timezonelist = new ArrayList<String>();

            timezonelist.add("Gvatemala");
            timezonelist.add("Gonduras");
            timezonelist.add("Batumi");
            timezonelist.add("Boston");
            timezonelist.add("Zhytomir");
            timezonelist.add("Zmerinka");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewOrderActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, timezonelist);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            timezonSpin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);timezonSpin.performClick(); 
            timezonSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {

                    Log.i("sd","Ya tut");
                    Log.i("choosed",timezonelist.get(position).toString());
                    timezoneEdit.setText(timezonelist.get(position));
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                    TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
                    String TimeZoneName = timezone.getDisplayName();
                    int TimeZoneOffset = timezone.getRawOffset()/(60 * 60 * 1000);
                    Log.i("timezone",Integer.toString(TimeZoneOffset));
                    timezoneEdit.setText("UTC"+Integer.toString(TimeZoneOffset), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                }
         });
```

try the above code. i think you have to make spinner object inside setOnClickListener event.

Answer (score 0):

Take the timezonSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener out the block timezoneEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { }

Comment: taked it to the onCreate() metod. But doesn't helped...(